How it is similar to integretion by parts?

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \frac{d g}{d x} d x=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d f}{d x} g(x) d x
$$
In book author says that is the "integration by parts", but i cant get how it related with common form of it:
$$
\int f g^{\prime} d x=f g-\int f^{\prime} g d x
$$
Where is $fg$? And it would be pretty, if someone help to understand the idea of transpose the derivative or any other function.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Welcome to MSE. I cannot see how the image you posted matches the question - they seem to be quite significantly different. Are you able to clarify what you are asking, beyond "where is fg?"?

The author works implicitly in a space of functions vanishing at $\pm\infty$.

It has to vanish at infinity since they are functions that verify $\int f^2 <\infty$

@julio_es_sui_glace $\int f^2 <\infty$ does not imply vanishing at infinity.
